# Weird Type Inference Behaviour in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-inference, typescript-generics, typescript-types

Assume this code:

```js
// base class:
class Pin<Output, Input=Output> {
  to<Out>(pin: Pin<Out, Output>): Pin<Out, Output> {
    return pin;
  }

  from<In>(pin: Pin<Input, In>): Pin<Input, In> {
    return pin;
  }
}

//some type aliasing for convenience:
type SyncFunc<I, O> = (i: I) => O;
type Resolve<T> = SyncFunc<T, void>;
type AsyncFunc<I, O> = (i: I, cb: Resolve<O>) => void;
type Func<I, O> = SyncFunc<I, O> | AsyncFunc<I, O>;

function src<Type>(): Pin<Type> { return new Pin<Type>(); }

function map<I, O>(m: SyncFunc<I, O>): Pin<O, I>;
function map<I, O>(m: AsyncFunc<I, O>): Pin<O, I>;
function map<I, O>(m: SyncFunc<I, O> | AsyncFunc<I, O>): Pin<O, I> {
  return new Pin<O, I>();
}
```

With this setup, the following code will have errors:

```js
src<number>().to(map((i, c: Resolve<number>) => c(i * 2))).to(map(x => x + 1));
```

As type of `i` is not properly inferred.

I can change the overloaded signatures arrangement like this:

```js
function map<I, O>(m: AsyncFunc<I, O>): Pin<O, I>;
function map<I, O>(m: SyncFunc<I, O>): Pin<O, I>;
function map<I, O>(m: SyncFunc<I, O> | AsyncFunc<I, O>): Pin<O, I> {
  return new Pin<O, I>();
}
```

Which fixes the issue with previous example, but causes an issue with this one:

```js
src<number>().to(map(i => i * 2)).to(map(x => x + 1));
```

Because the function passed to `map()` is now assumed to be of type `AsyncFunc`, the return type is not resolved, and so `x` is assumed to be of type `unknown`, which results in another error.

Wanted to open an issue on Typescript's GitHub, but thought of first asking here to ensure I'm not missing anything here. Is this expected behavior? i.e is it a bug with Typescript's type inference, or a feature that it currently lacks, or am I missing something?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using overloads here?  The two call signatures don't differ in number of parameters or in return type, so a single call signature of type `<I, O>(m: Func<I, O>): Pin<O, I>` should suffice (the same type as the implementation signature).  I'm not saying removing overloads would fix all your inference problems (you can't rely on inference of function parameters at the same time as you are inferring generic type parameters) but it would make the problem simpler.

Comment: not using the overloads, none of the inferences would work, i.e. both mentioned errors would happen.

Comment: I think one of the main issues here is that the value `x => x + 1` is assignable to both `SyncFunc<number, number>` and `AsyncFunc<number, number>` because of [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void). Overloads don't really help this; they just change which one it tries first.  I can write this up as an answer unless you have any outstanding questions.

Comment: Do you mean `i => i * 2`? Well it doesn't really match `AsyncFunc<number, number>`, since its return type isn't void (but a number).

Comment: I mean, you have both `i => i * 2` and `x => x + 1` in there, so whatever you think.  Try writing out `const f: AsyncFunc<number, number> = i => i * 2` and see how it does not result in an error.  The two links in my previous comment explain this; have you looked at them?

Comment: ok that helped. what you wrote is true, however it could be fixed by changing expected return type on `AsyncFunc` to `never`. that, combined with changing expected return type on `Resolve` to `never` as well, enabled typescript to properly infer all types. to be clear: I still need the overloads, and the overload for `AsyncFunc` should precede that for the `SyncFunc`.

Comment: @jcalz since your insight helped in finding a solution, would you want to write it as an answer or should I?

Comment: Yeah, I see if you would rather the compiler match one over the other ("when possible, match `AsyncFunc`, then try `SyncFunc`") then overloads can make that happen.  I'm writing up an answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue you're running into is the possibly-surprising type compatibility of a value like `x => x + 1` and `i => i * 2` with *both* `SyncFunc<number, number>` and `AsyncFunc<number, number>`:

```
const sf: SyncFunc<number, number> = x => x + 1; // okay
const af: AsyncFunc<number, number> = x => x + 1; // also okay... what?!
```

This is working as intended but confuses enough people that it's part of the [TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ).  I'll adapt the info there to this question:

Q: How could `x => x + 1` be assignable to `AsyncFunc` when the former accepts a single parameter while the latter requires two parameters?  [How could a function of one parameter be assignable to a function of two parameters?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)

A: `x => x + 1` is a valid assignment for `AsyncFunc` because it can safely ignore extra parameters.  At runtime, `(x => x + 1)(10, "randomExtraParam")` works.  Making this an error at compile time would end up invalidating a lot of conventional uses of methods like `Array.forEach()` or `Array.map()` whose implementation passes multiple parameters to the callback but are often used with callbacks of a single parameter.  You can read the FAQ entry linked above for why they think this is the best behavior here.

Q: How could `x => x + 1` be assignable to `AsyncFunc` when the former returns a `number` (assuming `x` is inferred as `number`) and the latter returns `void`?  [How could a function returning a value be assignable to one that doesn't?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void)

A: The `void` return type means that the caller cannot *expect* a return value, but it doesn't mean that there definitely won't be one.  It just means that the caller should ignore any value that's returned.  If you're ignoring any return value I give you, then it shouldn't matter if I `return 1` instead of `return undefined`.  Making this an error would end up invalidating a lot of conventional uses of callback-accepting-functions that don't consult the callback's return value, like `Array.forEach()`.  Some callbacks like `a => arr.push(a)` have both side-effects and return values, and forbidding return values would make it harder to use those in conventional ways.

---

In light of that, the behavior is understandable; the compiler cannot reliably distinguish between `AsyncFunc<number, number>` and `SyncFunc<number, number>`.  To make this happen, you should probably alter the types to be incompatible.  One way to do this is to make the return type of `AsyncFunc` something other than `void`, such as `undefined`:

```
type Resolve<T> = SyncFunc<T, undefined>;
type AsyncFunc<I, O> = (i: I, cb: Resolve<O>) => undefined;
```

They are similar, in that a function without a `return someValue` statement will end up returning `undefined`, but the compiler will now be unhappy if you return `1` instead of `undefined` in an `AsyncFunc`.

This still doesn't solve the problem of distinguishing functions by number of parameters.  If you just write the call signature of `map()` as `<I, O>(m: Func<I, O>): Pin<O, I>`, the compiler technically has enough information to see that `x => x + 1` must be a `SyncFunc`, but there's apparently too much for it to infer at once: it needs to infer both the type parameter `I` and the type of `x`, but those depend on each other and it gives up. Sometimes you can get it to work, but it's not always worth the effort.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134) for an issue and discussion surrounding the limitations of the current type inference algorithm and possibilities to improve it.

For now, though, you've already got a workaround that behaves the way you want: use [overloads](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to guide the compiler into first making a serious effort at interpreting `x => x + 1` as an `AsyncFunc`, have it fail (because of the incompatible return type) and then try `SyncFunc` and succeed.  This has the same problem as before about `I` and `x`, but the type `SyncFunc` is apparently simple enough for it to work (compared to `Func`).

That means the following works for you:

```
function map<I, O>(m: AsyncFunc<I, O>): Pin<O, I>;
function map<I, O>(m: SyncFunc<I, O>): Pin<O, I>;
function map<I, O>(m: Func<I, O>): Pin<O, I> {
    return new Pin<O, I>();
}

src<number>().to(map((i, c: Resolve<number>) => c(i * 2))).to(map(x => x + 1));
src<number>().to(map(i => i * 2)).to(map(x => x + 1));
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAECMEMGcFNQMYBsbQFwChmtABQJYB2APAPICuALgA5UA0oAkobZaALygU1UB8oAbwygRoSgHsyfABTUiaPESmUG3VrwCUCgiW6qq6wcNEmATrErlThUHMIBuYyIC+GJ6ABmp8QFtizXll5RRJmVgYArRD-FnomQn4hEzMLKxs7RxNXVwwQaF94SgBPanhIJHwYIgBzT3FTRHFCADdYQnw2hFhMYtLQAGUiwgQAMXJh-1V+Tml8BUYNDn5SR174ACVYfKRW4gAVaYGh0fGEfYZm8XwAE15VkvgAQWhjsYnGKY5QWfmGBHAFJttrtSJolqBLjd7n03mcPlxDoNhrDJgjQAAfUDPV6nVGgxwYDynSj4JqgaCmM57B6BKI6fY0wSgcyWaygQiwADu0WppVp9lAOSJwxJZJ8kGoeMCPgU2ORuPhoLpSlIETuhOJpJs4sliulCiRJ3eU2VujVjmFCFF2olUukMtAKL1prIaqMKVZNg53PpqqY-NAGByFLOhHIPnAsFMtIAdBJ7RLpLM-oCtuIdrBiGGI1Gwex+AhZqAAFSgABMGkrcfECeo0gAHuDGwBqUAARkrjhDWfDkej0g01drRfzoHwJfLVfjOobTdArY7GgJCCa0DY0A8BpxE2zfYYu9zX0bo5b7YFIFA4gA1pAilhV2xIJusS95Tve1H9x-o0e5wvz2A5T5JeN5FDG4GgJyAAWkCUAA-AAhG4hCQD4WzUJAXSOvgjZJKIeQFGIDygOUlTQDUdQNCuLRtB0wzdO4axHG+cKfDMcxMIso4rIxxFAumuwHF8hoonsDDjNcsAeEQsC3JkohMXKRqsWi7G-IgAKgPxGZkHm-ASVJMnXPJIhMU6bHMcpUoYi+24qfibgmJa1rkpSDJ8gO2hKLysCJMyqRst6PI0gOAo5E5mpiraer2rKr5Wc6Xlmv6JmeJFNq6lMsWWeZCIun6jDqhFIpaqAOp2g6uVKklrr+u6yQiCyaTsly0QFfy7jhaI3YHv2g7TomyaIKmwKZr1emIEWpYVlONYzse-CnouqU9d+sYDXW46juO02zcOC2gEtnZuEGQA)

Comment: p.s. actually changing the return type to `undefined` results in the compiler becoming unhappy with callbacks not returning any value, strangely enough. however, changing the return type to `void | undefined` surprisingly fixes the issue, as the compiler no longer expects return statements but properly infers the desired generics as well.